# Where to find wireless network drivers for HP62

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I've had to reinstall my laptop with Windows 7 64bit and have a hard time getting my WiFi to work again. My laptop's model is G62 a05SB and already went on HP's drivers website to look for the driver [here](http://h10025.www1.HP.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=nl&cc=be&dlc=nl&sw_lang=&product=4270435#N289). Only on this page there are 11(!) different drivers listed, I don't know my WiFi card's manufacturer so I have no clue which one to download.
I already tried several ones but they always turned out to be the wrong driver.

Anyone an idea how to find the right driver ?

some other data that may help identify the wireless card:
SN: 4CZ027026G
Product: XH463EA#UUG

Comment: Look on the HP sticker on the bottom or in the battery bay and post the full P/N product number and I can find which model wireless you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally Windows 7 is very good at analyzing your hardware and driver updates via Windows Update. These are normally presented as optional updates that you need to manually select in order to install. If you can get your computer connected to the Internet via a cable, it should do the work for you.

Another possibility if you can get an Internet connection is to let HP do the driver-detection for you : Go on the [English version](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4062&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=4270435) of the page you linked-to. This brings-up a dialog with a "Check now" option for HP to check all your drivers for you. Click it.
Next click "Verify products now". This will get you to a page that will ask to install software in your browser. Follow the steps. (This is where I stopped, since I don't have an HP computer.)

If this doesn't work for you, go into the Device Manager and look at the Properties of the network device. The exact model should be there.

For really difficult cases, the page [Best Free System Information Utility](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-system-information-utility.htm) lists several utilities that could give as much detail about your hardware as required to find out what model of card you have.

And finally, normally an installation of a network driver should fail if a compatible device is not found, so you could just try all the 11 possibilities. But I don't have experience with HP driver installations.

Answer (score 0):

- Windows automatic update will resolves hardware driver issues mostly, so check for updates then choose, custom install option now go through the optional updates section , Hardware section in your left pane & tick the check box if the update shown. If not then follow these manual steps.
- Download and install the Intel chipset driver first from the [link](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=nl&cc=be&dlc=nl&sw_lang=&product=4270435#N289) given by you .
- Then download Broadcom Wireless LAN Driver version 5.60.350.6 for Microsoft Windows 7 from the list .(this driver works on most laptops , if not try atheros).
- Now check for the previous driver which was not worked and uninstall it , By right click My computer -> Properties ->Device manager->
  [image]
- Now run the downloaded driver ,right click run us administrator (sp48591.exe),during this setup disable antivirus software and dont run any parallel installation . Now restart the computer .
- Now open Network sharing center by right clicking network icon in task bar, and click Change adapter settings , now check the Wireless icon. If listed then you installed successfully.
  [image]

  -If not now uninstall the same driver as described above and try Atheros driver .